# Windows 10 notification center hotkey

Tags: windows-10, hotkeys

Is there any hotkey for show/hide Notification center (and may be for other actions with notifications) in Windows 10?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> does the trick it seems for showing-hiding notification center. I just tried every single combination with Win key and came across this.

Answer (score 10):

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> works as posted above. This [list of other keyboard shortcuts](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/sebastianklenk/2015/05/28/windows-10-keyboard-shortcuts-at-a-glance/) might be helpful to you and others too.

Comment: Additionally, `Win+B` (not listed in the article) to set the focus to the System Tray